# NoMethodError in SessionsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When attempting to set up a Logout action, I create a Session#destroy method in the Sessions_Controller. Below is the full Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_session, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  helper_method :current_user

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to '/tasks'
    else
      redirect_to 'login'
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
```

log_out looks like this in sessions_helper.rb:

```
    def log_out
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
    end
```

I receive the below error when attempting to use the logout button I have set up or navigate to localhost:3000/logout.

Error Message

[image]

I cannot even find that code to look at it more closely. Any ideas?

Comment: So, where is your `set_session` method?

Comment: Show your `set_session` method

Comment: Remove `before_action :set_session, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`. Also you should use `reset_session` instead of `session.delete(:user_id)`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation

Comment: I created the controller using rails g scaffold_controller Sessions so that was auto created. Would that be required in this instance?

Comment: No - this is not a scenario that really fits the scaffold generator, as sessions are not like your average resource.

Comment: Just used Max's suggestion. It worked. Any insight on why scaffold auto generates the :set_x method and how necessary it is?

Comment: Run the scaffold generator `rails g scaffold thing` and you´ll see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # move this to ApplicationController instead of duplicating it all over your app
  helper_method :current_user 

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to '/tasks'
    else
      redirect_to '/login'
    end 
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end
```

---

```
def log_out
  reset_session
  @current_user = nil
end
```